# In CrafterCMS, how to setup the mail server properly?

Tags: email, configuration, smtp, content-management-system, crafter-cms

In **CrafterCMS**, I’m trying to configure a mail server, in the documentation I see two different locations to override the related properties:

http://docs.craftercms.org/en/2.5/system-administrators/tmp/installation-guides/configure.html?highlight=workflow

***TOMCAT/shared/classes/crafter/cstudio/extension/server-config.properties***

http://docs.craftercms.org/en/2.5/system-administrators/studio-configuration.html?highlight=mail%20server

***TOMCAT/shared/classes/crafter/engine/extension/studio-server-config.properties***

Is this a doc inconsistency or do they have different purposes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To configure Studio Email capabilities use this file
`TOMCAT/shared/classes/crafter/cstudio/extension/server-config.properties`

Comment: Note: That is valid for 2.5.x